# Search ALL instances of ##anything##

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have this regular expression in my Javascript code:

```
/##+[A-z]+##/
```

When using it on the following text:

```
<a href="EditUsers.aspx?UserName=##UserName##">##Address##</a>
```

it only matches `##UserName##`, whereas it should match both `##UserName##` and `##Address##`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't addresses typically have numbers in them? That regex looks to match letters

Comment: @user597419: It looks to me like he's trying to match the literal tags `##UserName##` and `##Address##`, probably for template variable substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `g` flag to perform a *global* search:

```
/##+[A-z]+##/g
```

---

BTW, are you sure about that first `+`? And case-insensitivity is usually done with the `i` flag.

Perhaps you want:

```
/##[a-z]+##/ig
```

Comment: +1, but that last point needs more emphasis: **`[A-z]` is an error**.  It includes several punctuation characters along with the uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters.